# What is causing asynchronous changes of permissions after usage of chmod in backticks in perl

Tags: perl, asynchronous, chmod

TL;DR - Go down to the *UPDATE* for a toy example.  The following was my original question before I was able to reproduce the issue in a small example, edited for clarity.

I do not understand what is going on here.  I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why a test I'd written in perl kept failing.

I was testing a function that turns off logging when an open of an output log file failed so that output to STDERR would not be suppressed.  To test that it works, I created a file on the fly and chmod it to be unwritable.  The resulting run of the code should print an open error along with all other STDERR to the STDERR output.  I was doing the chmod in backticks before running my test.

However, what was happening was the logfile kept getting written to without error - so the test was failing.  I started doing sanity checks by printing the output of `ls -halF` in various places to see where the permission change was happening.  The initial chmod seemed to be working:

```
`echo > file.log;chmod 444 file.log;ls -halF file.log`
```

A subsequent `ls -halF file.log` after some other setup confirmed the intended permissions, but a very early line of code in my run of the actual test code said that the owner had write permission!

I eventually discovered a fix to the problem - by using the perl `chmod()` method instead of chmod in backticks, which makes me think there's some asynchronous stuff going on - and that made no sense to me.

I ended up trying that because in my numerous tests, I would occassionally see a test randomly succeed.  So I wrote a quick loop to perform the same test over and over - and discovered that it randomly succeeds maybe 30% of the time!  That's what made me think there may be some sort of asynchronicity to this issue, which I could not explain because I thought that backticks essentially waited for the process to complete since it returns the output - so what is going on here?  I don't understand it.

For completeness - the actual test command is done in backticks too - it runs an independent script.

In my update below, I show a different case, but it demonstrates the randomness of the permissions states...

## UPDATE

OK.  This is a small self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.  Pay attention to the different output of the second line in each case...

### deleteme1.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print(`echo '' > deleteme.log;chmod 444 deleteme.log`);
print("1: ",`ls -l deleteme.log`);
`chmod 777 deleteme.log;rm -f deleteme.log`;
```

### deleteme2.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print(`echo '' > deleteme.log;chmod 444 deleteme.log`);
print("2: ",`ls -l deleteme.log`);
chmod 0777, "deleteme.log";
unlink("deleteme.log");
```

Now observe the output of this repeating loop:

```
tcsh> foreach f ( `seq 1 30` )
perl deleteme1.pl
perl deleteme2.pl
end
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 May 31 21:01 deleteme.log
```

Note that the owner permission differences are always from deleteme1.pl.  I think that the `@` indicates extended attributes on macOS.  That may have something to do with it, but there are cases where xattr is there, but no permission differences...

And I also suspect that the problem might possibly have something to do with this:

```
>ls -1 t | wc -l
   46391
```

So something's happening asynchronously - what the hell is it?!  Could it have something to do with SIP or csr(util)?

## UPDATE 2

Here's an example truer to my specific case.

### deleteme3.pl

This one represents my fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(TLG,">deleteme.log");
print TLG '';
close(TLG);
chmod 0444, "deleteme.log";
if(open(TEST,">deleteme.log"))
  {print "3 opened\n"}
else
  {print "3 unable to open\n"}
chmod 0777, "deleteme.log";
unlink("deleteme.log");
```

### deleteme4.pl

This one demonstrates the original problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
`echo '' > deleteme.log;chmod 444 deleteme.log`;
if(open(TEST,">deleteme.log"))
  {print "4 opened\n"}
else
  {print "4 unable to open\n"}
chmod 0777, "deleteme.log";
unlink("deleteme.log");
```

I looped on these 2, as above:

```
tcsh>foreach f ( `seq 1 1000` )
perl deleteme3.pl
perl deleteme4.pl
end
```

In the 1000 tries, `3 unable to open` was always output for `deleteme3.pl`.  `deleteme4.pl` outputs `4 opened` 4 times, and the rest are `4 unable to open`.

Obviously, this doesn't demonstrate the frequency I was seeing where most of the time, my permissions showed owner-writable, but my guess is I was hitting some sort of sweet spot where something was mucking with my file permissions.

I would love to see if someone can reproduce these results on any platform, but I'm on macOS Sierra (10.12.6) running the system perl version 5.18.2.

Comment: No research effort? I spent hours on this and have been using perl for 20 years. And who down-votes without commenting? Backticks are supposed to wait until the command is done: "executes a command and your perl script is continued after the command has finished." http://fibrevillage.com/scripting/373-what-s-the-difference-between-perl-s-backticks-system-and-exec

Comment: Re "*I thought that backticks essentially waited for the process to complete since it returns the output*", It does. The above executes `/bin/sh` with the arguments `/bin/sh`, `-c` and `echo > file.log;chmod 444 file.log;ls -halF file.log`. It waits for `sh` to return before continuing. As you said, it must since it collects the output of the child. Does that answer your question? If not, I don't know what it is.

Comment: So why the random test failures for the expected file permission errors that are fixed by using perl's chmod command?

Comment: The test was to set a logging flag when open for write failed so that output would go to stderr, but the file was actually getting written to. The open should fail with a permissions issue and set the logging flag accordingly.

Comment: It is impossible to say why the test is failing since you only show the part which you deem important - but which might not actually be the important part or not all what is important. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I know that open fails with a permissions error @ikegami, but as I said, "the first line of code in my run of the actual test code said that the owner had write permission". `ls -l` on line above the call to that script says r--. I do an `ls -l` in the init of the first used module in the script that's being run and it says `rw-`. So I'm not even sure how I would go about reproducing it. The module is large. Let me see if I can reproduce it in a small version, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: I can't believe I managed to create a reproducible example, but look at the update for definitive proof that my instinct was right. SOMETHING is happening asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the test snippet. That shouldn't happen (unless something is actively changing the permissions) X_X.  Can't replicate in Linux and Linux over WSL.

Comment: I'm guessing the async thing you are seeing may be the macOS GUI, but you only mentioned the Mac in passing. All the failing cases seem to have added extended attributes, so something about the Mac (Spotlight, etc) may happen to have visited when that version of the file happened to exist. But why are you shelling out for these things? What happens if you do the same from a shell script?

Comment: > “you only mention the Mac in passing”. - What’s your point? What are you trying to say by that? > “Why are you shelling out for these things?” - That’s not relevant to my question. I have a fix for this issue. The only reason I’m asking this question is to understand what’s going on in this case. > “What happens if you do the same thing from a shell script?” - Ok, so if the shell script doesn’t do this, are you suggesting that would rule out Perl? I don’t think it would given how dramatic the difference appears to be in my real test (which appears to hit a sweet spot) and my toy example.

Comment: Edit of my prev comment: *if the shell script *does* do this

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich - Yes, I know(/knew) it's impossible. I was was simply at a loss and I was hoping there was some obvious answer I was lacking about asynchronicity of permission operations and that doing this in backticks was conventionally avoided for unknown reason X. I should have realized those here would just assume I'd coded something wrong, because it makes no sense. I probably would have concluded the same thing if I were reading my own question, but at the same time, I knew my code wasn't responsible, so there didn't seem to be a way to prove it - because you can't prove a negative.

Comment: Perhaps this question should go on Server Fault or Super User instead? Is there enough evidence to say this isn't a code issue? In fact, could this literally be an overflow issue or even a security vulnerability? I should try to run my test in a directory that doesn't have 45k+ files.

Comment: If you want to actively resist help, why are you asking a question?

Comment: I just got annoyed with the down votes and the snide comments absent of any helpful suggestions on what to look for when I had no clue which way to go or what was even relevant. I was already frustrated having spent the better part of a day going crazy trying to figure it out myself. So I apologize that I got snippy with you. - So why do you think trying this in a shell script would get me closer to understanding what's happening in the perl code? Seems like either a positive or negative result WRT perms changes would be inconclusive.

Comment: I tried the example on my new laptop (running Catalina) (in a similarly large directory) and could not reproduce the random issue. I also re-tried on the Sierra laptop both in the large directory and in a small directory and reproduced the issue both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the culprit for the asynchronous permissions changes.  I was missing a critical piece of information in my question: the directory in which I was working was in Dropbox(!).  I was unaware that dropbox ever modifies the permissions of files, but apparently it does.

With the Dropbox app running:

```
tcsh>foreach f ( `seq 1 50` )
foreach? perl deleteme1.pl
foreach? perl deleteme2.pl
foreach? end
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -rw-r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -rw-r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--@ 1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:09 deleteme.log
```

After quitting Dropbox (still in the dropbox directory):

```
>foreach f ( `seq 1 50` )
foreach? perl deleteme1.pl
foreach? perl deleteme2.pl
foreach? end
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
1: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
2: -r--r--r--  1 robleach  staff  1 Jun  2 12:11 deleteme.log
```

I discovered this because I was suspecting that SIP was the culprit.  I rebooted in recovery mode and disabled SIP with `csrutil disable`.  After rebooting, I ran the test loop and saw the same behavior of randomly changing permissions, but while that was running, I got a dialog from dropbox saying "Dropbox need to change permissions for the Folder `/Users/robleach/Dropbox`".  I clicked `OK` and re-ran the loop and the random permissions issue was not evident.

I rebooted in recovery to re-enable SIP and rebooted again (with SIP active) just to confirm SIP was not involved.  I re-ran the loop and again saw the random permissions issue.  I then quit dropbox and re-ran the loop.  The results are above.

I openly admit that I lacked the knowledge for it to even occur to me to realize that the dropbox aspect of this issue would be critical to answering this question.^  And I admit that I have my development project in Dropbox out of laziness - so I don't have to remember to commit/pull unfinished changes between performing work on 2 different computers.  But I've had this specific project in dropbox for years and never ran into any issues until now (test #757, i.e. 756 tests performed as expected).  So it hadn't even occurred to me that Dropbox could be a factor in this issue.  I was unaware the sync made active changes to the files on the source device (i.e. where the file was created).

^ Cross-reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348841/stack-mechanisms-are-evolving-toward-an-ideal-that-hampers-collaborative-problem

Comment: Yeah, I suspected it was something like that. Dropbox likes to change the icon of the file its syncing, so you end up with writeable permissions and extended attributes. But, this is why we ask clarifying questions.

Comment: And, [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) does a lot less than people imagine it does. You wouldn't be able to create files in a directory protected by SIP. Not a big deal, but I've noticed in my own searches for help, various people quickly jump to "disable SIP" as a "have you tried turning it off and on again" approach.

Comment: That’s a good point about the icon changes. I only recently discovered SIP. It was a the cause of an issue where I encountered a bug in an app that added a quarantine flag. Actually, I forgot I’ve been meaning to answer that question. I had started to, but the 2 references where I discovered documentation on the bug needed more vetting. Then I got distracted and forgot about it. I tried disabling it when my Mac Mini was experiencing freezes and had an unresponsive process called SandboxedServiceRunner, but the freezes continued despite the disable, so I suspect you’re generally right.